# Show only one users specific columns from many randomly in laravel 5.4 query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have many columns in my 'users' table. I want to show just one user's first name and last name from many others columns in front page pop-up for all. User name will be changed in every refresh randomly. Please, someone help me.I tried something like bellow--

```
<?php
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->select('first_name','last_name')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->get();
        echo $users;
    ?>
```

It's showing all users and in key-value formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you just want to show 1 user then use `first()` instead of `get()`.

Then to get the first name and last name you would just access the properties on the object e.g.

```
$user = DB::table('users')
    ->select('first_name', 'last_name')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->first();

echo $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
```

Hope this helps!